# Webpack not worked

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have project with such structure:

```
Project
    node_modules
        ...
    com
        adding.js
        App.js
        Footer.js
        Todo.js
        TodoList.js
    action.js
    reducers.js
    store.js
    build.js
```

And I have this build file:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var config = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: ['redux', 'react', 'react-redux', './action', './reducers', './store', './com/adding', './com/Todo', './com/TodoList', './com/Footer', './com/App'],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'assets')
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"}
        ]
    }
};
var compiler = webpack(config);
compiler.run(function (err, stats) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error:' + err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Win');
    }
});
```

But when I compiled and start bundle.js I get this error: `Error: Cannot find module "./store"`. What's wrong? Files `reducers.js` and `action.js` work normal, but `store.js` and all files in folder `com` not find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `entry` parameter in `config` is wrong. Usually you specify one (or some) entry point here. In that file you can use `import` to import all dependencies you've now listed in the `entry` array.

I think [this starter repository](https://github.com/codeocelot/react-reflux-webpack-starter) can help you a lot setting up webpack, React and Reflux.